# Getting Compilation error while trying to change global variable value inside the main function in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int count;
int main()
{
    int k;
    cin>>k;
    count=k;
    cout<<count;
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to change the value of 'count' (Global Variable) in main function but getting `reference to 'count' is ambigous` error in C++. But the same kind of code works well in C. Please help me.

Comment: This is why [`#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [`using namespace std;` is bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice) and combined together they are horrible. `std::count` exists and now your compiler is confused what do you mean by `count`.

Comment: Include what you actually need and don't drag the entire standard library into the global namespace. `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;` are convenient, but they also have a cost.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen    I changed the variable name from "count" to something else. But still getting the same error.

Comment: `namespace std` is full of very common names, quite likely to that you shot into another one. The correct solution is to get rid of both `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` and replace it with `#include <iostream>` (and in futere any header that you need) and get rid of `using namespace std;` and use qualified names: `std::cout` and `std::cin` (eventually you can change `using namespace std;` to `using std::cout;` and `using std::cin;`, if you really want to save that 5 characters when printing and reading input)

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `using namespace std;` line, add the `std::` to `cin` and `cout` and it should be ok.

You have this compiler error because `std::count` exist: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/count
So it's ambigous for the compiler between `std::count` and your variable `count` because you use `using namespace std`.

Comment: I changed the variable name from "count" to something else. But still getting the error.

Comment: What did you change the name to?  You only need the `#include <iostream>` header and a `using std::cout;`.